# Genymotion dont run

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

When i run my project in Android Studio whit Genymotion, the following error is given:
I have Win 7, 32bit.
Please help me.
Thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtnDk.png)

Comment: does virtualbox run on your pc successfully ?

Comment: Yes ...........